# Move data from one form textbox to another in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have an invoice total form that should calculate the percentage discount among other things. I'm adding a second form to the code that allows you to change the sales tax I got it to populate the form and actually work with no errors but I can't get it to move the data from the textbox on frmSalesTax to the `txtSalesTax.Text` in frmInvoiceTotal.

frmInvoiceTotal Code:

```
 public frmInvoiceTotal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    frmSalesTax percent = new frmSalesTax();
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal productTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtProductTotal.Text);
        decimal salesTax = (7.75m/100m) *  productTotal;
        decimal discountPercent = .0m;

        if (productTotal < 100)
            discountPercent = .0m;
        else if (productTotal >= 100 && productTotal < 250)
            discountPercent = .1m;
        else if (productTotal >= 250)
            discountPercent = .25m;

        decimal discountAmount = (productTotal + salesTax) * discountPercent;
        decimal subtotal = productTotal - discountAmount;
        decimal invoiceTotal = (subtotal + salesTax) - discountAmount;


        txtSubtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString("c");
        txtSalesTax.Text = salesTax.ToString("c");
        txtDiscountPercent.Text = discountPercent.ToString("p1");
        txtDiscountAmount.Text = discountAmount.ToString("c");
        txtTotal.Text = invoiceTotal.ToString("c");

        txtProductTotal.Focus();
    }

private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        percent.salesTax = txtSalesTax.Text;
        switch (percent.ShowDialog())
        {
            case DialogResult.OK:
                txtSalesTax.Text = percent.salesTax;
                break;
        }

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

    }
```

invoiceTotal GUI:[image]

frmSalesTax Code:

```
 public partial class frmSalesTax : Form
{
    public string salesTax
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public frmSalesTax()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.salesTax = txtPercent.Text;
        txtPercent.Text = "";

        Hide();


    }
```

I know I'm missing something but I can't figure out what it is.

salesTax GUI: [image]

Comment: Where is the problem then, you never set `salesTax` in `frmSalesTax` and you never use it in other form

Comment: I set it as percent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea making a property on `frmSalesTax` to communicate...but you're not really using it.

In your `frmInvoiceTotal`, you need to send the current value to `frmSalesTax.salesTax` and then handle the results of the percent dialog returning `DialogResult.OK`:

```
private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    percent.salesTax = txtSalesTax.Text; //--> send current value to frmSalesTax
    switch ( percent.ShowDialog() ) //--> ShowDialog will return the DialogResult of the pressed button
    {
       case DialogResult.OK:
         txtSalesTax.Text = percent.salesTax;  //--> update with new value from frmSalesTax
         break;
    }                    
}
```

...and, in your `frmSalesTax`, you need to put the `txtPercent.Text` into the `salesTax` property when the user clicks the OK button:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.salesTax = txtPercent.Text;  //--> frmInvoiceTotal will read this after the OK button is clicked
    txtPercent.Text = "";

    Hide();
}
```

**Important**: you have to make sure the `frmSalesTax` buttons have their `DialogResult` set, so that `frmInvoiceTotal.btnOk_Click` knows that it's okay to get the value:

[image: DialogResult property]

**Edit**

The property (in `frmSalesTax`) needs to *not* be based on the form's text values...because you're setting that to "" when the form hides. This is what you want for the property:

```
public string salesTax
{ 
  get;
  set;
}
```

This would go with the other changes I mentioned earlier.

**Edit 2**

It's easy to get frustrated. There are a lot of moving pieces, and I can understand how the eyes can cross. Here's the crux of the issue - your calculation is trashing things on you;-)

These lines in the `btnCalculate_Click`:

```
decimal salesTax = (7.75m/100m) *  productTotal;
decimal discountPercent = .0m;
//...
txtSalesTax.Text = salesTax.ToString("c");
txtDiscountPercent.Text = discountPercent.ToString("p1");
```

...should be the *initial values* and come in the form's initialization code:

```
public frmInvoiceTotal()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   decimal salesTax = (7.75m/100m) *  productTotal;
   decimal discountPercent = .0m;
   txtSalesTax.Text = salesTax.ToString("c");  //--> the initial value
   txtDiscountPercent.Text = discountPercent.ToString("p1");
}
```

...and then, the calculation should *not* re-populate `txtSalesTax.Text` or `txtDiscountPercent.Text`. The txtSalesTax.Text might be update from showing `frmSalesTax`, and I'm guessing you're gonna make another form to override discount percent at some point.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal productTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtProductTotal.Text);
    decimal salesTax = Convert.ToDecimal(salesTax.Text) * productTotal;  //--> if it got changed in frmSalesTax
    decimal discountPercent = .0m;

    if (productTotal < 100)
        discountPercent = .0m;
    else if (productTotal >= 100 && productTotal < 250)
        discountPercent = .1m;
    else if (productTotal >= 250)
        discountPercent = .25m;

    decimal discountAmount = (productTotal + salesTax) * discountPercent;
    decimal subtotal = productTotal - discountAmount;
    decimal invoiceTotal = (subtotal + salesTax) - discountAmount;


    txtSubtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString("c");
    //txtSalesTax.Text = salesTax.ToString("c"); //--> don't do this...it steps on what came from frmSalesTax
    //txtDiscountPercent.Text = discountPercent.ToString("p1");  //--> when you add another form to override this
    txtDiscountAmount.Text = discountAmount.ToString("c");
    txtTotal.Text = invoiceTotal.ToString("c");

    txtProductTotal.Focus();
}
```

I bet this get you a lot closer :-)

Comment: I did exactly what you put and it still didn't work. It's still only showing the sales tax that's a default.

Comment: Oh!  I see the bug...the property...hang on...I'll edit to show

Comment: no that still didn't work >.< I'm getting frustrated with this one now for sure. is that edit in frmInvoiceTotal or frmSalesTax?

Comment: Put all your current, updated code in the question...let's have a look

Comment: I have an error code CS1061 'decimal' does not contain a definition for 'Text'

Comment: That's on line 29 for salesTax.Text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190179/discussion-between-amanda-and-clay).